# Trigger filtering outside of AngularJS data table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following [codepen](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/oNNPNMK) where I am trying to learn how to filter data based on a clicked span element. The data is being displayed in a table. The angularjs documentation provides information on using the filter along with the ng-repeat attribute not sure how to go about triggering the filtering outside of the table. In my case I want to be able to change the data being displayed when a specific span element is clicked. How should I approach this? I have a openModal function that displays a modal when a button is clicked but I don't have to do anything to the display of the data for that to work. Thank you.

HTML

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 my-auto">
          <span>All</span>
          <span>Hawks</span>
          <span>Sparrows</span>
          <span>Doves</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 my-auto">
          <label class="my-auto float-right">Search:
            <input ng-model="searchText">
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row table-responsive">
        <table id="searchTextResults" class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th ng-click="sortBy('ID')">ID</th>
                <th ng-click="sortBy('Name')">Bird Name</th>
                <th ng-click="sortBy('Type')">Type of Bird</th>
            </tr>
          <tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="birds in list | filter:searchText | orderBy:sortField:reverseOrder">
              <td><a href="#">{{birds.ID}}</a></td>
              <td><a href="#">{{birds.Name}}</a></td>
              <td><a href="#">{{birds.Type}}</a></td>
<td><button ng-click="openModal()" class="myBtn">Edit</button></td>
            </tr>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add ng-click function to the span element and when you click on that, you set the searchText. refer the demo below. You can further simplify this, instead of hard coding span elements , you can dynamically generate using ng-repeat, So that if you add any new span element, just add it in the array. Hope this helps.

Simplified version will be look like this.

```
<span ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-click="update(tab.value)">{{tab.label}}</span>

 $scope.tabs = [ { value: '', label: 'All' }, { value: 'Dove', label: 'Doves'}]; 

 $scope.update = function(filterText) {
      $scope.searchText = filterText;
 }
```

```css
span {
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 my-auto">
          <span ng-click="update('')">All</span>
          <span ng-click="update('Hawk')">Hawks</span>
          <span ng-click="update('Sparrow')">Sparrows</span>
          <span ng-click="update('Dove')">Doves</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 my-auto">
          <label class="my-auto float-right">Search:
            <input ng-model="searchText">
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row table-responsive">
        <table id="searchTextResults" class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th ng-click="sortBy('ID')">ID</th>
                <th ng-click="sortBy('Name')">Bird Name</th>
                <th ng-click="sortBy('Type')">Type of Bird</th>
            </tr>
          <tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="birds in list | filter:searchText | orderBy:sortField:reverseOrder">
              <td><a href="#">{{birds.ID}}</a></td>
              <td><a href="#">{{birds.Name}}</a></td>
              <td><a href="#">{{birds.Type}}</a></td>
<td><button ng-click="openModal()" class="myBtn">Edit</button></td>
            </tr>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myController',
        function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.list = [
  {
     "ID": "001",
     "Name": "Eurasian Collared-Dove",
     "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "002",
      "Name": "Bald Eagle",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  },
  {
      "ID": "003",
      "Name": "Cooper's Hawk",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  },
  {
      "ID": "004",
      "Name": "Bell's Sparrow",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "005",
      "Name": "Mourning Dove",
      "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "006",
      "Name": "Rock Pigeon",
      "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "007",
      "Name": "Abert's Towhee",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "008",
      "Name": "Brewer's Sparrow",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "009",
      "Name": "Canyon Towhee",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "010",
      "Name": "Black Vulture",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  },
    {
     "ID": "011",
     "Name": "Eurasian Collared-Dove",
     "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "012",
      "Name": "Bald Eagle",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  },
  {
      "ID": "013",
      "Name": "Cooper's Hawk",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  },
  {
      "ID": "014",
      "Name": "Bell's Sparrow",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "015",
      "Name": "Mourning Dove",
      "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "016",
      "Name": "Rock Pigeon",
      "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "017",
      "Name": "Abert's Towhee",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "018",
      "Name": "Brewer's Sparrow",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "019",
      "Name": "Canyon Towhee",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "020",
      "Name": "Black Vulture",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  },
        {
     "ID": "021",
     "Name": "Eurasian Collared-Dove",
     "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "022",
      "Name": "Bald Eagle",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  },
  {
      "ID": "023",
      "Name": "Cooper's Hawk",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  },
  {
      "ID": "024",
      "Name": "Bell's Sparrow",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "025",
      "Name": "Mourning Dove",
      "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "026",
      "Name": "Rock Pigeon",
      "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "027",
      "Name": "Abert's Towhee",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "028",
      "Name": "Brewer's Sparrow",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "029",
      "Name": "Canyon Towhee",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "030",
      "Name": "Black Vulture",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  }
  ];
  $scope.count = $scope.list.length;
  $scope.reverseOrder = true;
  $scope.sortField = 'ID';
    
  $scope.sortBy = function(sortField) {
  $scope.reverseOrder = ($scope.sortField === sortField) ? !$scope.reverseOrder : false;
      $scope.sortField = sortField;
  };
    
    $scope.openModal = function() {
      debugger
      modal.style.display = "block";
    }
    
    $scope.update = function(filterText) {
      $scope.searchText = filterText;
    }
  });

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  console.log("button clicked");
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```